# Reorganize columns from several CSV files into a set of new files

Tags: matlab, csv, file-io, export-to-csv, data-manipulation

I have 14 CSV files and each has 100 columns, what I want to do is to extract first column from each file and all first columns to a single csv file. I have to do it for each of the 100 columns (for example next step is to put second column from each file in a csv file).

What I've tried before is the code below which is doesnt work, I want to put what I mentioned above in a loop so I get the 100 files at once. How can I do it?

```
clear;
clc;
files= dir('C:\Users\lighting\Desktop\New folder\*.csv');
num_files = length(files);
N = sort_nat({files.name});
for i=1:num_files
    data = xlsread(N{i});
    PathLength = data(:,1); % read the 1th column from the csv file
    filename = 'last.csv';
    dlmwrite(filename,PathLength,'-append')
end
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you want to turn the 14 files into 100 files?

Comment: @Dev-iL That's right!

Comment: Depending on your application, it would be easier to use a `datastore` / `tall` tables, which are designed for exactly this purpose (treating data across multiple files as a single table with continuous columns). Aside from that, it is very relevant here to know how big your files are and how much RAM you have - if you can load and store all the data in memory then this becomes very easy!